# WCF InstanceContext Error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-callbacks

publisher and subscriber concept using WCF, publisher(Server) to develop in WCF service and subscriber(Client) to develop in windows application. Publisher to create a proxy and to implement i got error

"The InstanceContext provided to the ChannelFactory Contains a UserObject that does not implement the CallbackContractType 'IRegistrationCallback'.

```
enter code here
```

### Server Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace ServerApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IService1, IDisposable
    {
        ServiceHost EventServiceHost = null;
        ServiceHost SubscriptionServiceHost = null;
        private bool disposed = false;
        string EndPoint1 = string.Empty;
        string EndPoint2 = string.Empty;
        string EndPoint3 = string.Empty;
        string EndPoint4 = string.Empty;
        string BaseAddress1 = string.Empty;
        string BaseAddress2 = string.Empty;
        FileStream fs = null;
        StreamWriter m_streamwriter = null;
        Subscription Subscribe = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LogFile("Service Sucessfully lunched");
        EndPoint1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EndpointAddress1"];
        EndPoint2 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EndpointAddress2"];
        EndPoint3 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EndpointAddress3"];
        EndPoint4 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EndpointAddress4"];
        BaseAddress1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BaseAddress1"];
        BaseAddress2 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BaseAddress2"];
        InitializeOperation();
        Subscription.GetClientEvent += new GetClientListHandler(Subscription_GetClientEvent);
        Subscription.RemoveClientevent += new RemoveCleintListHandler(Subscription_RemoveClientevent);
        Subscribe = new Subscription();
    }

    void Subscription_RemoveClientevent(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            string data = (string)obj;
            LogFile("Client Remove sucessfully: " + data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile("Client Remove failure: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void Subscription_GetClientEvent(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            string data = (string)obj;
            LogFile("Client Connect sucessfully: " + data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile("Client Connect failure: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    ~Form1()
    {
        CleanUp(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CleanUp(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void CleanUp(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
            }
            try
            {
                if (EventServiceHost != null)
                    EventServiceHost.Close();
                if (SubscriptionServiceHost != null)
                    SubscriptionServiceHost.Close();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        disposed = true;
    }

    public void InitializeOperation()
    {
        try
        {
            Uri BaseAdrs1 = new Uri(BaseAddress1);
            Uri BaseAdrs2 = new Uri(BaseAddress2);
            EventServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Publishling), BaseAdrs1);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding wsDualBindingPublish = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding tcpBindingPublish = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

            EventServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEvent), wsDualBindingPublish, EndPoint1);
            EventServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEvent), tcpBindingPublish, EndPoint2);
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            EventServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            try
            {
                EventServiceHost.Open();
                LogFile("Publish Service Host open Sucessfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogFile("Publish Service Host open failure: " + ex.Message);
            }
            SubscriptionServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Subscription), BaseAdrs2);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding wsDualBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

            SubscriptionServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRegistration), wsDualBinding, EndPoint3);
            SubscriptionServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRegistration), tcpBinding, EndPoint4);
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb1 = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb1.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            SubscriptionServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb1);
            try
            {
                SubscriptionServiceHost.Open();
                LogFile("Subscription Service Host open Sucessfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogFile("Subscription Service Host open failure: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile("Service Host Configuration failure: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Register(object obj)
    {
        Subscribe.Register(obj);
    }

    public void UnRegister(object obj)
    {
        Subscribe.UnRegister(obj);
    }

    public string GetDateTime()
    {
        return Subscribe.GetDateTime();
    }
    public void LogFile(string Data)
    {
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\WCFLogs.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamwriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamwriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " : " + Data + "\n");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            m_streamwriter.Flush();
            m_streamwriter.Close();
            m_streamwriter = null;
            fs.Close();
            fs = null;
        }
    }

    private void btnEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                Publishling ob1 = new Publishling();
                AlertData alertdata = PrepareAlertForReceiver();
                ob1.OnClient(listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex], checkBox1.Checked);
                ob1.OnEvent(alertdata);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private AlertData PrepareAlertForReceiver()
    {
        AlertData e = new AlertData();
        e.SeqNo = "1";
        e.Description = "WCF Event";
        e.wer = "fg";
        return e;
    }
}

}
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Register(object obj);
    [OperationContract]
    void UnRegister(object obj);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetDateTime();

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}

[ServiceContract]
interface IEvent
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnEvent(AlertData e);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnClient(object obj, bool check);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IEvent))]
public interface IRegistration
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Register(object obj);

    [OperationContract]
    void UnRegister(object obj);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetDateTime();
}

[DataContract]
public class AlertData
{
    private string _SeqNo;
    private string _Description;

    [DataMember]
    public string wer;

    [DataMember]
    public string SeqNo { get { return _SeqNo; } set { _SeqNo = value; } }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get { return _Description; } set { _Description = value; } }

}


public delegate void GetClientListHandler(object obj);
public delegate void RemoveCleintListHandler(object obj);

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Subscription : IRegistration
{
    public static event GetClientListHandler GetClientEvent;
    public static event RemoveCleintListHandler RemoveClientevent;

    static List<IEvent> m_ClientList;
    static List<object> ObjClientList;
    public GetClientListHandler ClientHandle = null;
    public RemoveCleintListHandler RemoveClinet = null;

    public Subscription()
    {
        m_ClientList = new List<IEvent>();
        ObjClientList = new List<object>();
        ClientHandle = new GetClientListHandler(GetClientLists);
        GetClientEvent += ClientHandle;
        RemoveClinet = new RemoveCleintListHandler(RemoveClientLists);
        RemoveClientevent += RemoveClinet;
    }

    internal static IEvent[] GetClientList()
    {
        lock (typeof(Subscription))
        {
            return m_ClientList.ToArray();
        }
    }

    internal static object[] GetClientListWithObj()
    {
        lock (typeof(Subscription))
        {
            return ObjClientList.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public void Register(object obj)
    {
        lock (typeof(Subscription))
        {
            IEvent Subscriber = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEvent>();
            if (m_ClientList.Contains(Subscriber))
            {
                return;
            }
            m_ClientList.Add(Subscriber);
            ObjClientList.Add(obj);
            GetClientEvent(obj);
        }
    }

    public void UnRegister(object obj)
    {
        lock (typeof(Subscription))
        {
            IEvent Subscriber = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEvent>();
            m_ClientList.Remove(Subscriber);
            ObjClientList.Remove(obj);
            RemoveClientevent(obj);
        }
    }

    public string GetDateTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    public void GetClientLists(object obj)
    {

    }

    public void RemoveClientLists(object obj)
    {

    }
}

public class Publishling : IEvent
{
    object ClientObj = null;
    bool CheckAll = false;

    public void OnEvent(AlertData e)
    {
        if (CheckAll)
        {
            IEvent[] Subscribers = Subscription.GetClientList();
            Type type = typeof(IEvent);
            MethodInfo methodinfo = type.GetMethod("OnEvent");

            foreach (IEvent Subscriber in Subscribers)
            {
                try
                {
                    methodinfo.Invoke(Subscriber, new object[] { e });
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            IEvent[] Subscribersevent = Subscription.GetClientList();
            object[] Subscribers = Subscription.GetClientListWithObj();
            Type type = typeof(IEvent);
            MethodInfo methodinfo = type.GetMethod("OnEvent");
            foreach (object Subscriber in Subscribers)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ClientObj == Subscriber)
                    {
                        methodinfo.Invoke(Subscribersevent[i], new object[] { e });
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                catch
                { i++; }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnClient(object obj, bool check)
    {
        ClientObj = obj;
        CheckAll = check;
    }
}
```

### App.Config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseAddress1"  value="http://192.168.0.194:8001/PublishingService/" />
    <add key="BaseAddress2"  value="http://192.168.0.194:8002/SubscriptionServie/" />
    <add key="EndpointAddress2"  value="net.tcp://192.168.0.194:8004/PublishingService" />
    <add key="EndpointAddress1"  value="http://192.168.0.194:8003/PublishingService/" />
    <add key="EndpointAddress4"  value="net.tcp://192.168.0.194:8006/SubscriptionServie" />
    <add key="EndpointAddress3"  value="http://192.168.0.194:8005/SubscriptionServie/" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

### Proxy Code

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3053
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Runtime.Serialization;



[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="AlertData", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/")]
public partial class AlertData : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject

{


private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

private string DescriptionField;

private string SeqNoField;

private string werField;

public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
{
    get
    {
        return this.extensionDataField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.extensionDataField = value;
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string Description
{
    get
    {
        return this.DescriptionField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.DescriptionField = value;
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string SeqNo
{
    get
    {
        return this.SeqNoField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SeqNoField = value;
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string wer
{
    get
    {
        return this.werField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.werField = value;
    }
}
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="IRegistration", CallbackContract=typeof(IRegistrationCallback))]
public interface IRegistration
{


[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/Register", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/RegisterResponse")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AlertData))]
void Register(object obj);

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/UnRegister", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/UnRegisterResponse")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AlertData))]
void UnRegister(object obj);

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/GetDateTime", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/GetDateTimeResponse")]
string GetDateTime();
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public interface IRegistrationCallback
{


[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/OnEvent")]
void OnEvent(AlertData e);

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IRegistration/OnClient")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AlertData))]
void OnClient(object obj, bool check);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public interface IRegistrationChannel : IRegistration, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public partial class RegistrationClient : System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase<IRegistration>, IRegistration

{


public RegistrationClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance) : 
        base(callbackInstance)
{
}

public RegistrationClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName) : 
        base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName)
{
}

public RegistrationClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
        base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
{
}

public RegistrationClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
        base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
{
}

public RegistrationClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
        base(callbackInstance, binding, remoteAddress)
{
}

public void Register(object obj)
{
    base.Channel.Register(obj);
}

public void UnRegister(object obj)
{
    base.Channel.UnRegister(obj);
}

public string GetDateTime()
{
    return base.Channel.GetDateTime();
}
}
```

### Proxy Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IRegistration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IRegistration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.194:8005/SubscriptionServie/"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IRegistration"
                contract="IRegistration" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IRegistration" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.0.194:8006/SubscriptionServie"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IRegistration"
                contract="IRegistration" name="NetTcpBinding_IRegistration" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

### Client Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ClientApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static int eventReceiveCount;
        static int astaEventReceiveCount;
        WCFIntermediate CommunicationObject = null;
        string EndPoint = string.Empty;
        string EndPoint1 = string.Empty;
        static object ClientObj = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeClient();
    }

    private void InitializeClient()
    {
        EndPoint = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EndpointAddress"];
        EndPoint1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EndpointAddress1"];

        CommunicationObject = new WCFIntermediate();
        if (rbtnHttp.Checked)
        {
            CommunicationObject.MakeClient(EndPoint1, this, 1);
        }
        else if (rbtnTcp.Checked)
        {
            CommunicationObject.MakeClient(EndPoint, this, 0);
        }
        eventReceiveCount = 0;
        astaEventReceiveCount = 0;
    }

    public void OnEvent(AlertData e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            int itemNum = (lvAsta.Items.Count < 1) ? 0 : lvAsta.Items.Count;
            lvAsta.Items.Add(itemNum.ToString());
            lvAsta.Items[itemNum].SubItems.AddRange(new string[] { e.SeqNo.ToString(), e.Description });
            astaEventReceiveCount += 1;
            txtAstaEventCount.Text = astaEventReceiveCount.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnClearAstaListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lvAsta.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = CommunicationObject.GetDateTime();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            ClientObj = addr[0].ToString() + ":" + rnd.Next(5);
            if (CommunicationObject == null)
                InitializeClient();
            CommunicationObject.Subscribe(ClientObj);
            ((Button)sender).Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).Enabled = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        CommunicationObject.UnSubscribe(ClientObj);
        CommunicationObject = null;
    }

    private void rbtnTcp_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtnTcp.Checked)
        {
            if (CommunicationObject == null)
            {
                CommunicationObject = new WCFIntermediate();
                CommunicationObject.MakeClient(EndPoint, this, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void rbtnHttp_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtnHttp.Checked)
        {
            if (CommunicationObject == null)
            {
                CommunicationObject = new WCFIntermediate();
                CommunicationObject.MakeClient(EndPoint1, this, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}



class WCFIntermediate
{
    IRegistration m_Proxy;

    public void MakeClient(string EndpoindAddress, object CallbackInstance, int TcpOrHttp)
    {
        if (TcpOrHttp == 0)
        {
            NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            EndpointAddress endPointaddress = new EndpointAddress(EndpoindAddress);
            InstanceContext Context = new InstanceContext(CallbackInstance);
            m_Proxy = new RegistrationClient(Context, netTcpBinding, endPointaddress);
        }
        else if (TcpOrHttp == 1)
        {

            WSDualHttpBinding DualHttpBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None);
            EndpointAddress endPointaddress1 = new EndpointAddress(EndpoindAddress);
            InstanceContext Context1 = new InstanceContext(CallbackInstance);
            m_Proxy = new RegistrationClient(Context1, DualHttpBinding, endPointaddress1);

            string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            //IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            DualHttpBinding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + addr[0].ToString() + ":4000/");
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe(object obj)
    {
        m_Proxy.Register(obj);
    }

    public void UnSubscribe(object eventOpertion)
    {
        m_Proxy.UnRegister(eventOpertion);
    }

    public string GetDateTime()
    {
        return m_Proxy.GetDateTime();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What did you want to achieve? I could not get the issue conceptually.

Comment: We really don't need to know all your code including the code generated by Add service reference. If you want to pass some code make simple reproducible example of your problem. Btw. it is also good practice to build application incrementally - adding features when something already works.

Answer (score 1):

Your client part does not implement IRegistrationCallback.